# Compare data element with partial mean in d3

Tags: d3.js, comparison, mean, partial

I have the following data

```
 [{"devcount" : 1  , "dayofweek" :0, "hour" : 1  },
  {"devcount" : 2  , "dayofweek" :0, "hour" : 2  },

  {"devcount" : 3  , "dayofweek" :1, "hour" : 2  },
  {"devcount" : 4  , "dayofweek" :1, "hour" : 3  },
  {"devcount" : 6  , "dayofweek" :1, "hour" : 4  },
  {"devcount" : 5  , "dayofweek" :1, "hour" : 5  },

  {"devcount" : 7  , "dayofweek" :2, "hour" : 5  },
  {"devcount" : 8  , "dayofweek" :2, "hour" : 6  },
  {"devcount" : 9  , "dayofweek" :2, "hour" : 7  },
  {"devcount" : 10 , "dayofweek" :2, "hour" : 9  }]
```

It is required to compare the `devcount` with the group average of `devcount` for each `dayofweek`.
i.e. for the fist row, `devcoun`t=1 is to be compared with the the average device count for the `dayofweek`-0 (= 1.5) and "yes" to be returned if the `devcount` is lesser. Else "No" should be returned.

I have coded as below.

```
smry=d3.nest()
.key( function(d) { return d.dayofweek;}) 
.rollup(function(d) {return d3.mean(d, function(g) {return g.devcount; })})        
.entries(result);
```

I am not sure how to compare the smry data and the original data.
The original data will be used in selectAll for creating rectangles and the output after comparison needs for determining the colour of the rectangle

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you have tried so fat (with `map`, `filter`, `d3.mean` or anything else). Otherwise, it seems that you want people to write code for you, for free. In that case, I'm out.

Comment: As hint i would suggest you to look into d3.nest and d3.mean that should help you.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo and Cyril. I have no clue how to proceed with this. I am not an expert in d3. I tried with d3.nest() but not able to combine the resultant data with this data

Comment: I coded as below    
`smry=d3.nest().key( function(d) { return d.dayofweek;})
       .rollup(function(d) {return d3.mean(d, function(g) {return g.devcount; })})
       .entries(result);`

Comment: Thanks for posting it, @Arun, but please don't post it in the comments, edit your question and post the code there. This way, it's easier for people reading the question (not everybody reads the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as shown in the snippet below.

```js
 test = [{
     "devcount": 1,
     "dayofweek": 0,
     "hour": 1
   }, {
     "devcount": 2,
     "dayofweek": 0,
     "hour": 2
   },

   {
     "devcount": 3,
     "dayofweek": 1,
     "hour": 2
   }, {
     "devcount": 4,
     "dayofweek": 1,
     "hour": 3
   }, {
     "devcount": 6,
     "dayofweek": 1,
     "hour": 4
   }, {
     "devcount": 5,
     "dayofweek": 1,
     "hour": 5
   },

   {
     "devcount": 7,
     "dayofweek": 2,
     "hour": 5
   }, {
     "devcount": 8,
     "dayofweek": 2,
     "hour": 6
   }, {
     "devcount": 9,
     "dayofweek": 2,
     "hour": 7
   }, {
     "devcount": 10,
     "dayofweek": 2,
     "hour": 9
   }
 ];

 //make the summary using nest
 smry = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d) {
     return d.dayofweek;
   })
   .rollup(function(d) {
     return d3.mean(d, function(g) {
       return g.devcount;
     })
   })
   .entries(test);
test.forEach(function(t) {
    //find the value from summary for dayofweek
    var k = smry.find(function(s) {
        return (s.key == t.dayofweek)
    }); 
    //check the day of week with the mean, set the flag in the data
    if(k.values<t.devcount){
      t.flag = true;
    } else {
        t.flag = false;
    }
});

console.log(test);//this now has the flag to determine the color
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```